# what is uninitialized data in pytorch.empty function

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, memory-management, pytorch, tensor

i was going through `pytorch` tutorial and came across `pytorch.empty` function. it was mentioned that empty can be used for **uninitialized data**. But, when i printed it, i got a value. what is the difference between this and `pytorch.rand` which also generates data(i know that rand generates between 0 and 1). Below is the code i tried

```
a = torch.empty(3,4)
print(a)
```

Output:

> ```
> tensor([[ 8.4135e-38,  0.0000e+00,  6.2579e-41,  5.4592e-39],
>         [-5.6345e-08,  2.5353e+30,  5.0447e-44,  1.7020e-41],
>         [ 1.4000e-38,  5.7697e-05,  2.5353e+30,  2.1580e-43]])
> ```

```
b = torch.rand(3,4)
print(b)
```

Output:

> ```
> tensor([[ 0.1514,  0.8406,  0.2708,  0.3422],
>         [ 0.7196,  0.6120,  0.4476,  0.6705],
>         [ 0.6989,  0.2086,  0.5100,  0.8285]])
> ```

[Here is the link to official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.empty)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you call [`torch.empty()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.empty), a block of memory is allocated according to the size (shape) of the tensor. By *uninitialized data*, it's meant that [`torch.empty()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.empty) would simply return the values in the memory block as is. These values could be default values or it could be the values stored in those memory blocks as a result of some other operations, which used that part of the memory block before.

---

Here's a simple illustration:

```
# a block of memory with the values in it
In [74]: torch.empty(2, 3)
Out[74]: 
tensor([[-1.0049e+08,  4.5688e-41, -9.1450e-38],
        [ 3.0638e-41,  4.4842e-44,  0.0000e+00]])

# same run; but note the change in values.
# i.e. different memory addresses than on the previous run were used.
In [75]: torch.empty(2, 3)
Out[75]: 
tensor([[-1.0049e+08,  4.5688e-41, -7.9421e-38],
        [ 3.0638e-41,  4.4842e-44,  0.0000e+00]])
```

Comment: Thanks, so...every time i run it, a new block gets allocated and so, the values in that block might be returned?

Comment: do you have any reference of where you got this info?

Comment: This `torch.empty()` is an alternative to `numpy.empty()`; Some more information can be found here: https://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-When-is-numpy-empty-useful

Comment: i have one more question . i created a question. can you answer it if you know it. This is the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152658/building-reccurant-neural-network-with-feed-forward-network-in-pytorch